# How to lower the bibliography's title by 3.3cm? And change its alignment?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

I'm running a pretty hacked-up template for my thesis, and the bibliography chapter's title is now too high. (This is due to various changes to the 'normal' chapter titles and their alignment/spacing, changes that I'd like to keep.)

So essentially I'd like to add in a `\vspace{3.3cm}` before the "References" title. How can I do this? (Using `BibTeX` and `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, if it makes any difference. The normal "Bibliography" title has been changed to "References".)

Bonus if I can re-align it too back to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using BibTeX, right? Either way, I think you need to do a `\renewcommand` on the `thebibliography` environment, probably along the following lines of the code below (to be inserted in your document's preamble).

Do note that the example assumes you're using the `book` or the `report` documentclass (or one that's derived from them); if you use the `article` documentclass, you'll need to replace the command `\chapter*` with `\section*` (one occurrence). I've gone ahead and inserted the required name of the bibliography, viz. "References".

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}{} %% to suppress the numeric labels (only if needed)
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     %% If using article documentclass, replace 
     %% "\chapter*` with "\section*" below
     {\chapter*{References}%   
      \phantom{a}\vspace{3.3cm}
      \@mkboth{References}{References}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Separately, I'm not sure what you mean by "Bonus if I can re-align it too back to the left." If you mean that you don't want an indent of entries after the first line, try issuing the command `\renewcommand{\bibindent}{0pt}`. If you mean that you want to suppress the `[.]` numeric labels, you'd have to issue the command `\renewcommand{\@biblabel}{}`, best immediately after the `\makeatletter` instruction. Or, do you mean you want the text to be *left-justified* (as opposed to "fully justified")? If so, just issue the command `\raggedright` before starting the bibliography. Better yet, load the `ragged2e` package in the preamble and then issue the command `\RaggedRight`. The latter command is preferable because it doesn't suppress hyphenation.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Mico. I tried to implement the code and got the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Command \thebibliography already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.167      \phantom{a}
                      \vspace{3.3cm}
?

Comment: You're right -- I meant to say `\renewenvironment` instead of `\newenvironment`. I've fixed the typo in the answer above.

Comment: I feel bad to ask again, but now the code added gives this error: ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
<argument> \@biblabel {##
                         1}
l.178 ...enewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}
                                                  %
?

Comment: Did you remember to place the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands around the redefinition of the thebibliography environment? Another possibility: did you replace *all three* instances of `\bibname` with `\refname` (if you're using an `article`-type document class)? [Can you tell I'm stumbling in the dark?]

Comment: Arrgh, just discovered another error, now corrected in the code above. (I hadn't moved the `\phantom...` commands inside the first brace. Yikes!) Hope it works for you now!

Comment: Yay, it now runs without error. (BTW it's a book document class, to answer your question.) However, the code behavior is different than anticipated. What it does is add another page to the previous chapter, but leaves the "References" chapter heading unmoved. I tried to increase the spacing drastically (e.g., from 3.3cm to 6.3cm) and there's no shift. But the code is definitely on the right track, because I can use this redefined environment to, for example, rename "References" to something else. So the code is being read/used by my document. But \phantom{a}\vspace{3.3cm} isn't as expected.

Comment: I'm glad the code now works, at least in a narrow sense. In a `book` class, each `\chapter` and `\chapter*` command generally starts a new page before typesetting the chapter's caption. From your description, one or more of the packages you load are altering this default behavior in rather, shall we say, unusual ways?

Comment: I'll preface this by saying that I'm out of my element, but... wouldn't the \chapter* command start the new page and do the typesetting only after it is called? So since the \phantom and \vspace commands are before the \chapter* command, they'd be part of the preceding chapter, no? (Which is what is observed.) I'm wondering whether the \phantom and/or \vspace should be called after the \chapter* command, not before? I'm sure I'm wrong for some reason, but it'll be interesting to find out why :) Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Update - fixed it by moving the \phantom and \vspace commands inside the \chapter* title, i.e.: \chapter*{\phantom{a}\vspace{3.3cm}References}% It's probably not the 'proper' way to do it but it appears to work beautifully, so as long as nothing breaks I'm happy. Thank you very much for all your help Mico!

Comment: Congrats on finding the fix! I'll update the code in the answer above to reflect your insight.